# How can I fix this leaky roof over a covered open air porch?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, water-damage, ice

There is a small deck above this covered porch. The first picture shows right below that deck where there is small shingled roof. Below this roof is a covered but open to the air porch. When the snow melts from the deck water drips down and freezes on the siding as shown circled in red.

Once everything melted I noticed big bubbles in the paint from the wood siding shown in the second picture. Clearly I have a water problem. Can I fix this the right way in the middle of winter? If not any good mitigation ideas while I wait for spring?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the roof isn't actually leaky. You just need a better drip scenario?

Comment: I guess it's not the roof exactly but where the roof meets the siding.

Comment: Ice is just a bad deal; it seems like you'd do well to shed the snow/water sooner rather than let it melt and flow through that deck to re-freeze on the roof below.

Comment: @GregHill Yes I know that now and will be shoveling the deck off in the future but this is the first year this has happened so I assume something has deteriorated and I want to fix it.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood what I was seeing. Looks like you have a problem with the flashing against the wall, or the ice dam is backing water up underneath the shingles. It's hard to say until you address the ice.

Comment: @isherwood Well the ice is gone now. I'd like to do some sort of fix. This didn't happen last year despite that roof being covered with ice all winter.

Comment: The fix is always the same--figure out what's leaking. We can't tell from here, but it's likely related to the step flashing against the wall. You'll probably have to take some things apart and trace the staining.

Comment: The location of the wall ice is suspicious. It could be the upper deck flashing, or the junction of the deck and the roof. Those are common trouble spots. It could also be the top edge of the shingles where they meed the deck framing.

Answer (score 1):

That little shingled roof under the deck would be a really bad idea, because replacing the shingles will be next to impossible. So it smacks of an after-though project and I'd venture to say that they didn't properly flash that roof to the siding, meaning the flashing needed to go UNDER the siding. Fixing it properly now could be really expensive because it may require removing the deck to get at the upper corners. What they likely did was just run a bead of caulking along the roof-to-siding seam, and that didn't last long. What you can probably do now if you don't want to tear anything out is to preemptively remove and replace that caulking every once in a while, maybe based on how long it had been working for you until now. Use a butyl caulk, they last longer in applications like this.